# pandas drop_duplicates works but when saved using .to_csv it still shows all

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I'm simply trying to remove duplicates from a csv and then make a new csv file with only the first column and no duplicates.

My terminal shows its working but when then the new csv file still shows all. ???

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#df = pd.read_csv('directory.csv',index_col=0,usecols=["From"]),
d = pd.read_csv('directory.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['From'])


print(
    """
    
    
-----this is all phone numbers in header FROM-----


    """
)

print(df)
print(
    """


-----this is only unique values ----


    """
)

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="From", keep="first", inplace=True)
print(df)

print(
    """


-----now saving to new csv----


    """
)

df.to_csv("uniquePhones.csv")
```

Terminal
python3 csvImport.py

-----this is all phone numbers in header FROM-----

```
                              From
0       +34141414)
1      1231231231
2       1231213
3                  (+123123123
4       123212313..                             ...
692    1231237)
693  A123213616)
694    12321433)
695    1312)
696  1321321)

[697 rows x 1 columns]
```

-----this is only unique values ----

```
                              From
0       +34141414)
1      1231231231
2       1231213
3                  (+123123123
4       123212313.. 
692    1231237)
693  A123213616)
694    12321433)
695    1312)
696  1321321)

[279 rows x 1 columns]
```

-----now saving to new csv----

Comment: You can not use inplace=True and re-assign to a variable.  If you use inplace=True the return will be None.

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="From", keep="first", inplace=True)`  is incorrect.  Use inplace=False OR remove 'df =' from in front.

Comment: I changed it to false it works but the CSV file still shows all rows.

Comment: -----this is only unique values ----


    
                              From
0       +234131
1      Ja134134131231)
3         32434234314
5       13414241
6      3413131)
..                             ...
689    12341231231
691    1311312
693  1231231231)
694    123213213
695    132131

[279 rows x 1 columns]



-----now saving to new csv----

Comment: My terminal says lists all the rows then has this
[279 rows x 1 columns]

is it not replacing df with the new set?

Comment: This works. I think it was the dataset I was using.


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = pd.read_csv('us-500.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['phone1'])


print(
    """
    
    
-----this is all phone numbers in header Phone1-----


    """
)

print(df)
print(
    """


-----this is only unique values ----


    """
)

df = df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
print(df)

print(
    """


-----now saving to new csv----


    """
)

df.to_csv("uniquePhones.csv", index=True)

Comment: Solved it! The code works, it was just the type of CSV file I was using. When it was converted from Excel, it was some random UTF-8 CSV type. I made it to a plain CSV file and it all worked fine. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm happy it worked for.   Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, fixed it by doing:

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index()
df.to_csv() # Now works
```